# Print multiple copies of report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have MainReport with header band and some subreports in detail band.

I would like to print it for example 3 times, with different footer.

How to manage it?

Comment: How will the footers differ?

Comment: in each footer will be another text, for example Copy for me, Copy for you and Copy for him.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Report Groups in your report with footer and header.

What you have to do just go to Ireport and add Report Group with footer and header then copy the same report or graph and header in each footer and header , there you can add extra text for every copies.